# LeafletJS Version Update

Tags: html, leaflet

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />


        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
        <link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/MarkerCluster.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />


       <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="script/leaflet.makimarkers.js"></script>  
        <script src="leaflet-providers/leaflet-providers.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jQuery/jquery-1.11.1-min.js"></script> 
        <script src="script/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="map" style="width: 1895px; height: 940px;"></div>


        <script src="script.js"></script>        

     </body>

</html>
```

This HTML works fine, however when I change leaflet to a new version,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />


        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
        <!--<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/MarkerCluster.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

        <script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js'></script>
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css' rel='stylesheet' />

       <!-- <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script> -->
        <script src="script/leaflet.makimarkers.js"></script>  
        <script src="leaflet-providers/leaflet-providers.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jQuery/jquery-1.11.1-min.js"></script> 
        <script src="script/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="map" style="width: 1895px; height: 940px;"></div>


        <script src="script.js"></script>        

     </body>

</html>
```

I got the error;

TypeError: t is undefined

Could any leafletjs expert help me to figure out what is going on, please?

Comment: what's inside your script js?

Comment: @Monkey_Dev1300, I added a piece of the script above.

Comment: The only thing that should be in your `<head>` are your stylesheets, everything else should be where your script tag is in the `<body>`

Comment: Make sure your Leaflet plugins are compatible with Leaflet 1.x.x. There were a number of API change compared to version 0.x.x.